# List Processes into Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Title says it all, I've tried doing this..

```
private void Constructor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessListBox.Items.Add(Process.GetProcesses());
}
```

But when ran it writes "Process[] Array" Please help me out.

Comment: I think it should be `ProcessListBox.Items.AddRange`

Comment: Welcome!  Try to put a bit more effort into your question such as describing _what_ it should be doing.  _"title says it all"_ - isn't particularly helpful, that's why there is a title and question body.  [ask]. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When you add items to `ListBox` it calls it's `.ToString()` method to somehow show it to user.

You have to get process names and then add them all to `ListBox`.

```
private void Constructor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessListBox.Items.AddRange(
                Process.GetProcesses()
                    .Select(process => process.ProcessName)
                    .ToArray());
}
```

You may receive a warning about casting `string[]` to `object[]` on runtime.
You can fix it by adding redundant explicit cast:

```
private void Constructor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessListBox.Items.AddRange(
                (string[]) Process.GetProcesses()
                    .Select(process => process.ProcessName)
                    .ToArray());
}
```